# Android - Activity inside linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an app with a WebView and an invisible menu on top of the page (it only appears when double clicked on the screen). That menu is a simple linear layout with buttons inside. Each button will start a different activity and I would like to make it so the menu would work in all activities. 
I was thinking of creating a main layout that would consist of (invisible) menu on top and on the rest of the screen it would have the space for other activities. I want each activity to have its own layout aswell.
Maybe I could create that layout with menu on top and the rest of the space would be linear layout. Then I would call each activity inside that linear layout.
Is that possible and if it is, how to do it?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion better solution would be to create this invisible menu in one main activity and than add / replace fragments depending on pressed button. This way you invisible menu will be drawn only in one activity and all the fragments will have it's own custom layout.

Comment: All activities contentView's layout relativeLayout or FrameLayout? If not you must use relativeLayout or framelayout.

Comment: You can do that using fragments..Create a fragment for the invisible menu and another fragment for main layout...for more info refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thank you for quick replies. I haven't tried fragments yet since I'm new to android programming. I'll surely try that out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating one `Activity` which have your invisible layout at top and a `FrameLayout` as container for your `Fragments` :

**MainActivit.java**

```
public class MainActivity(){

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

and **activity_main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invisible_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <!-- your other views here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/invisible_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

That's the `MainActivity` which will hold all your `Fragments`. For using `Fragments` in your app you should check [Android Developers - Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

**Edit:** Here is how you can add/replace `Fragments` via code:

To add your first `Fragment` simply call :

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.commit();

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

And after that to replace the content with another `Fragment` , you should do something like this in your `onClick` :

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

So basically you should use `FragmentTransaction.add()` and `FragmentTransaction.replace()` .

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to start a WebView fragment inside OnCreate of MainActivity? Thank you

Comment: Create a Fragment and add a WebView as it's content. It's almost the same way as you will do it in Activity

Comment: ok I created a class for fragment and inserted the code and then I added that fragment to FrameLayout inside activity_main.xml. It works fine, but how can I call it from MainActivity and not from xml file? Or at least how would I call another fragment when button is pressed?

Comment: Did I miss something? I get an error "ExampleFragment cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: `ExampleFragment` is your `Fragment` which you want to use to replace the first one. It's just an example, you should create another Fragment and replace it.

Comment: ok, that works now that I changed that. But I have another problem. Menu that I have doesn't work anymore because I'm using fragments.
You can see the problem here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448093/android-double-tap-webview-detect) but this solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I gave you a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448093/android-double-tap-webview-detect) **<--- here it is**. It's a linear layout with some buttons inside that was supposed to hide when double clicked on the screen and reappear when double clicked again.

Answer (score 1):

as i understand you can do it like that :

1- create a class which extneds LinearLayout for the menu. 
2- create a class extends activity and inside of it create that menu view
3- all your other activities should extends the activity you created in step 2. 
4- inside all other activities onStart you should add menu view to the screen

but i strongly suggest you to use navigation Drawer.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html and 
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support older versions of Android (i.e. avoiding fragments), you can use an `<include>` to add the menu layout to each activity. You'll need to hook up the click events in the onCreate of each activity, though you can encapsulate this code in another class.